# Y Chromosome in Ovary Cancer Data

Tags: genetics, cancer, human-genetics, tcga, icgc

I have been analyzing TCGA Ovary Cancer data. In ***Somatic Mutation*** data, there is data of mutations in all the chromosomes (*1-22 and X*), but amazingly, I have found one (*just one*) row of ***Y Chromosome*** mutation as well. What can it mean?

For Reference, I have pasted that row below:

```
icgc_mutation_id icgc_donor_id project_code chromosome chromosome_start 
MU42454          DO28056       OV-US        Y          13500742         

chromosome_end chromosome_strand mutation_type            
13500742       1                 single base substitution 

reference_genome_allele mutated_from_allele mutated_to_allele 
G                       G                   A                 

consequence_type aa_mutation cds_mutation gene_affected   transcript_affected 
stop_gained      R194*       580C>T       ENSG00000183704 ENST00000331172
```

Comment: In just one individual you mean? It means that there was a rare recombination event I guess in the father (or grand-father or grand-grand...-father)

Comment: Yeah it is for one individual and only one entry: Individual is a 76yo female (deceased)

Comment: Does it correspond to a region the is close to the PAR?

Comment: Just to expand on what @Remi.b said, there is the possibility that at some point in the past, in a male ancestor, a rare event occurred where a portion of the Y chromosome somehow ended up grafted to an X chromosome (or possibly any one of the others), but didn't cause enough issues/abnormalities to be an issue, or at least noted.

Comment: You can find the positions of the PAR on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoautosomal_region#Location)

Comment: Its not in PAR of either X or Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked more than six years ago.  Since then, the dataset in question has been updated.  I accessed the OV-US project dataset from the [ICGC Data Portal](https://dcc.icgc.org/releases/current/Projects/OV-US), specifically `simple_somatic_mutation.open.OV-US.tsv.gz`. The 9<sup>th</sup> field of this file is `chromosome`.  Counting the occurrence of each chromosome, we see that Y is not represented:

```
awk -F$'\t' '{print $9}' simple_somatic_mutation.open.OV-US.tsv | sed '1d' | sort -n | uniq -c

  13171 X
  39564 1
  31363 2
  24657 3
  11021 4
  16849 5
  18643 6
  19492 7
  13067 8
  11133 9
  12090 10
  24980 11
  25608 12
   3947 13
  12728 14
  12123 15
  17554 16
  30315 17
   5669 18
  29571 19
   9054 20
   3639 21
   7084 22
```

Note that `icgc_mutation_id` MU42454 is only associated with [acute myeloid leukaemia in a single donor](https://dcc.icgc.org/mutations/MU42454). Moreover, the search scheme "`Donor` IS `DO28056` AND `Mutation Location` IS `ChrY`" yields [zero results](https://dcc.icgc.org/search/m?filters=%7B%22donor%22:%7B%22id%22:%7B%22is%22:%5B%22DO28056%22%5D%7D%7D,%22mutation%22:%7B%22location%22:%7B%22is%22:%5B%22chrY%22%5D%7D%7D%7D) from the ICGC data browser.

So, it seems that the inclusion of a Y chromosome mutation in the TCGA Ovary Cancer data was a mistake that has since been corrected.

Comment: Nice to see the correction